# Rails - difference between request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] and request.remote_ip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am adding some changes to existing RoR application and found out that `request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` returned `nil`. I changed that to `request.remote_ip` and got right IP address of the client.

Why does `request.remote_ip` return an IP when `request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` returns `nil`? What's the difference between them? How can I make `request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` work and which one should I use (best practice)?

Comment: X-Forwarded-For is used by HTTP proxies and load balancers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, you should use `request.remote_ip`. It is a method introduced by Rails which tries to gather the actual remote IP of the connection using various means, including evaluating `request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` where appropriate.

In the end, the IP returned by `request.remote_ip` is calculated in the [ActionDispatch::RemoteIp middleware](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.4/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb#L133-L163). This is a good bit more generic than trying to gather the IP yourself as it takes proxy stages into account which can set various HTTP headers.